# Managing Controller Code not Handled by a Function

Tags: angularjs

I have the following routing defined:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', { redirectTo: '/articles' });

  $routeProvider.when('/articles', { 
    controller: "ArticleCtrl",
    templateUrl: "/myApp/article/index"
  });

  $routeProvider.when("/articles/new", {
    controller: "ArticleCtrl",
    templateUrl: "/myApp/article/create"
  });
});
```

Here is my controller:

```
app.controller("ArticleCtrl", function($scope, $location, $log, articleService) {
  $scope.currentArticle = null;

  if ($location.path() == "/articles") {
    $scope.articles = articleService.list();
  } 

  $scope.saveArticle = function() {
    articleService.save($scope.currentArticle);
  } 
});
```

Regarding the `if ($location.path() == "/articles")`; I'm doing this because when my view changes to the "/articles/new" path which is controlled via a link like:

```
<a href="/myApp/#/articles/new">Add Article</a>
```

The controller was calling my service to get the list of articles back again.  A few questions:

- I thought that the controllers were singletons if it was already in memory once, it wouldn't call it again
- Is what I did to work around the problem an OK solution?
- If not, what is the AngularJS way for handling this?

Comment: No, controllers are not singletons. Why not make two different controllers?

Comment: Because both views belong to the same domain, Article.  To me, that is one controller.

Comment: The [angular documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.mvc.understanding_controller) explicitely says: *In general, a controller shouldn't try to do too much. It should contain only the business logic needed for a single view.*

Comment: So by that logic, I should have a ListArticlesCtrl and a CreateArticleCtrl (or some such naming) ?

Comment: Yes. You're free to do what you want, of course, but having a single controller do various things depending on what the location is seems wrong to me.

Comment: Coming from a server side MVC POV, that doesn't jive.  But I'm willing to accept this should be treated differently.

Comment: Ok, made the changes.  If you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept it.